# iptables mangle

Tags: ip6tables

I undetstand that mangle is used to alter the headers of the packet. But I couldn't understand what exactly the following command will do?

```
ip6tables -t mangle -A OUTPUT -s '1955:1890:1401:24FF::/64' -j DSCP --set-dscp 26
```

I am new to linux. someone please explain what will be the behavior of above command

Answer (score 1):

The command changes DSCP field to 26 of each packet leaving the computer with that command active, and coming from addresses `1955:1890:1401:24FF::/64`. iptables can manipulate packets on INPUT, FORWARD, OUTPUT. You command does the mangle before packet leaves.

Value DSCP header is for differentiated services (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiated_services), which determine the Quality of Service. The command adjusts some kind of priority for the packets coming from that address. Value 26 determines a class of Assured Forwarding for the packet.